# Opening a file from Terminal to a new window of TextWrangler

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editors, textwrangler

I'm able to open a file form Terminal with

```
open -b com.barebones.textwrangler whicheverfile
```

The problem is if any window of Textwrangler window is already is open, this file is open in that window. I want to keep enable preference option 'New & opened documents: Open in front window' while opening through Finder. Is there any terminal arguments which I can provide with above command to override the set preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open -b com.barebones.textwrangler -n whicheverfile
```

-n opens in a new instance. you can check out all of the options with

```
open --help
```

EDIT: open will duplicate items. Use

```
edit --new-window whicheverfile
```

or if you want multiple files

```
edit --separate-windows file1 file2
```

Comment: It still opens the file into already opened window, even though a new instance of textwrangler is invoked.

Comment: very strange. Try using edit, which uses textwrangler:

    edit --new-window whicheverfile

or if you want multiple files

    edit --separate-windows whicheverfiles

Comment: Yes, I started using 'edit' with bash wrapper. I was using Textwrangler from App Store. So had to download and install Textwrangler Command-Line Tools Installer from http://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/index.html to make this work.

Comment: oh interesting. I though textwrangler was still only downloaded separate from the appstore. So did the edit command answer your question?

Comment: yes, it did. I can accept the answer if you could update the answer also with 'edit' command. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I still had the problem of the file "opening" in the existing window until I realized that the file was opened there before I executed the command.  When I closed the file from the existing window and reexecuted the command, it opened in a new window.